# How I can Import font in SVG file?

Tags: xml, svg, font-face

I want to use more font in my SVG file.
Is there any solution?

My Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:#ff5" />
<text fill="#EEE" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#666666" stroke-width="2" class="test" x="0" y="900" font-size="200" font-family="SomeFont">
**SOME TEXT**</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sure, it works exactly the same as it does for html. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: i want to create svg file with php dynamic.i use <defs><style type="text/css">@import url(svg-stylesheet.css);</style></defs> and doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this after your `<?xml?>` processing instruction:

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="external_stylesheet_url.css" ?>`

This is documented in [Associating Style Sheets with XML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/).